# How to dispose a TeeChart in PHP

Tags: php, teechart

How can I dispose a Tchart?  Because, after some charts in a for, new Tchart hangs by out of memory.

Thanks in advance

```
while (...)
{
            $chart1 = new TChart(400,250);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've modified some classes, adding some __destruct() functions to dispose memory. It isn't still perfect but improving.

Could you please write to "info at steema dot com" referencing this thread so we can send you the modified files?